# Why GeoJSON is gotten by Leaflet, but does not display?

Tags: geoserver, leaflet, javascript

I WFS request from Leaflet to GeoServer is successful (200). But no features have been displayed. Response of request is big GeoJSON with features. What is the problem and what is wrong with my code (how to display features)? I used one from examples from StackOverflow answers.

```
var owsrootUrl = 'http://gis-domen/geoserver/ows';

               var defaultParameters = {
                    service : 'WFS',
                    version : '2.0',
                    request : 'GetFeature',
                    typeName : 'test_osm:my_points',
                    outputFormat : 'application/json',
                    format_options : 'callback:getJson',
                    SrsName : 'EPSG:3857'
                };

                var parameters = L.Util.extend(defaultParameters);
                var URL = owsrootUrl + L.Util.getParamString(parameters);

                var WFSLayer = null;

                var ajax = $.ajax({
                    url : URL,
                    dataType : 'json',
                    jsonpCallback : 'getJson',
                    success : function (response) {
                        WFSLayer = L.geoJson(response, {
                            style: function (feature) {
                                return {
                                    stroke: false,
                                    fillColor: 'black',
                                    fillOpacity: 0
                                };
                            },
                            onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
                                popupOptions = {maxWidth: 200};
                                layer.bindPopup("geom"
                                    ,popupOptions);
                            }
                        }).addTo(mymap);
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Did you check in debugger contents of `response` in `$.ajax` call ?

Comment: @TomazicM ```message: "response is not defined"
stack: "ReferenceError: response is not defined↵    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (file:///D:/index.html:74:17), <anonymous>:1:1)↵    at file:///D:/index.html:101:17"
__proto__: Error```

Comment: If you set break at line that starts with `WFSLayer = L.geoJson(response, { ...`, you should be able to inspect value of `response`.

Comment: @TomazicM Thanks, but no. ReferenceError: response is not defined for every strings

Comment: If setting debug break does not work for you, use `console.log(response)` to inspect response.

Comment: the parameters state jsonpcallback is getJson, but i don't see any getJson function defined.

Comment: comment out format_options and jsonpcallback lines